# Restore /boot/efi

Tags: mount, uefi, grub-efi

Recently I apparently corrupted my /boot/efi partition, I got according error messages at boot and a manual console to remount it.

I tried to reformat it (mkfs.vfat 32), reinstalled grub (grub-install), and updated fstab to the new UUID, however now it still fails to mount with `FAT-fs (sda1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: since /boot/efi became corrupted I slapped together a vulgar [script to recreate /boot/efi](https://github.com/coderinside/scripts/blob/master/restoreBootEfi.sh). Use at your own risk!

After finding the message above (by entering the manual recovery commandline offered and running `dmesg | tail`) I tried manual mounting. This failed as well.

Googling turned up that one should check whether the module `nls_iso8859-1.ko` could be loaded. So I tried running `sudo modprobe nls_iso8859-1`. This turned up an error about nort beeing able to open the dependency database. Recreating the dependency database with `depmod` fixed the issue.

Comment: `depmod` fixed it for me, Thanks!

Comment: 'depmod' saved my day. Thx, i am writing from the rescued machine :)