# 16.04 - stuck in emergency mode - FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found

Tags: boot, mount

My lenovo t470s laptop, running ubuntu 16.04 boots me into emergency mode.  Things were ok yesterday.

Details...

Running `mount /boot/efi`, yields `FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found` and `Mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p1, missing codepage or helper program or other error`

Running `systemctl —failed`, tells me that `boot-efi.mount` and `systemd-modules-load.service` have failed

Kernel is: 4.10.0-33generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Errors (and select warnings) found with `jounralctl -xb`:

- `Could not open moddep file:
  ‘lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic/modules.dep.bin’`
- `Failed to lookup alias ‘lp’: Function not implemented` (This repeats
  2 more times with a couple of variations)
- `dns-clean.service: Job dis-clean.service/start failed with result
  ‘dependency’`
- `local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result
  ‘dependency’`
- `FAT-fs (nvme0np1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found`
- `boot-eft.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32` `Failed
  to mount /boot/efi`

It's possible some updates installed yesterday, but unfortunately I don't recall what they were.

I'm unclear how to debug/fix things to get them back to a runnable state.  Any help is appreciated!

And of course, let me know what else I can provide to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Hard to know. Boot an old kernel - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/372445/fat-fs-sdc1-io-charset-iso8859-1-not-found-error-while-mounting-fat-drives or try https://askubuntu.com/questions/571643/restore-boot-efi

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, Thank you for the reply.  How do i boot to an old kernal from emergency mode?

Comment: To boot an old kernel see https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version

Comment: The error says "IO charset iso8859-1 not found", So,try enable CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_1 and rebuild the kernel.

Comment: Rebuilding the kernel should only be a solution to problems that have risen from the use of custom kernels in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Executing the following command in recovery mode solved the problem for me:

`$ depmod`

Comment: Worked for me as well. First press enter to login than `depmod` and `exit`. Could start and restart the system again.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: I actually believe my file system went corrupt during a reboot.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with a Lenovo T480s and Mint 19.2 (built on Ubuntu 18.04).

```
$ modprobe nls_iso8859-1
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.0-66-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: Module nls_iso8859-1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-66-generic
```

As suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/571644/415610), running:

```
$ depmod
```

in recovery mode, then rebooting fixed the problem for me.

Comment: That solved my issue, thank you.

Comment: The error occurred out of the blue and gave me a mini heart attack. This little solution worked for me and saved me a *LOT* of headache. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think my file system is damaged somehow, this error might be a cause of a bigger issue, namely a correct filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed, I think...Thanks all who helped.

Unfortunately the exact method by which it was fixed is unclear.  Due to my growing frustration and need to get things fixed, I was not atomic enough in my troubleshooting process, so it may of been one of two things, both suggested by @bodhi.zazen in comment above.

Either:

1. From recovery mode,
   running the modprobe commands here:
   https://askubuntu.com/a/571644/699673
2. Booting into a previous version of the kernel (from recovery mode, I selected an earlier version of the kernel from the list of options).

I performed these two operations in succession, so it is unclear which fixed things.

I have updated and rebooted several times thus far.  If anyone can suggest further checks to run to confirm stability, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I went through the same steps atomically and choosing the `previous version of the kernel` allowed me to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/nvme0nXpY is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0nXpY` # replacing X and Y with the numbers you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. **I apologize for the lack of formatting on this comment...**.  I tried both methods, neither worked.  
Booting into USB key, output of sudo fsck -f /:
    fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
    fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
    /dev/nvme0n1p1: 8 files, 870/130812 clusters . 

Gparted reported 3 partitions:  
    /dev/nvme0n1p1 | name:EFI system partition | file system: fat32 | size:512 MB | Used 4.41 MB | flags: boot, esp . 
    /dev/nvme0n1p2 | name: | file system: ext2 | … . 
    /dev/nvme0n1p3 | name: | file system: crypt-auks | … .

Comment: @devlindeboree  Normally you'd place that output into your original question using copy/paste. I think that some of your information got cut off, but since you booted from the USB flash drive, the command would probably be `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p3`.