# Restore boot partition via Ubuntu boot/loader

Tags: live-usb, bootloader

I'm trying re-install a boot-loader in Ubuntu 18.04 / I follow all the standard steps (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)/ But after I reboot it shows this message:

```
failed to create unit file /run/systemsd/generatpr/-.mount
```

I have tried to delete this file as well and run the automatic boot-loader steps again... but nothing seems to work or change anything...even though everything runs with success when I follow all the steps...

The reason why I have this issue is that I by accident earlier created the boot partition on one SSD (and all other partitions on another SDD) which now has been formated...

my boot-info file look like this:

```
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20200623_2047]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, nvme0n1p1 
                       starts at sector 0. But according to the info from 
                       fdisk, nvme0n1p1 starts at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32800 of /dev/sda1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on nvme0n1p3

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, bionic, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,6978b9e0-60b5-402c-b99e-66b8b52c1a4e,0x800,0x1e8000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0001  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0200)..GO..NO..........S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .9.7.0. .P.R.O. .1.T.B...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A...........................%8\.........4..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.S.4.6.2.N.F.0.K.C.0.0.4.6.0.R........BO..NO..........S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .9.7.0. .P.R.O. .1.T.B...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A...........................%8\...$.....4..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.S.4.6.2.N.F.0.K.C.0.0.8.5.5.B........BO
Boot0002  USB KEY   BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0b00)..GO..NO..........K.i.n.g.s.t.o.n.D.a.t.a.T.r.a.v.e.l.e.r. .3...0...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.............................F..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.D.0.6.7.E.5.1.6.4.F.9.1.F.1.2.0.2.6.0.4.4.0.8.6........BO
Boot0003* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0, Partition 1   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x2abf727,0x800,0x1cd125a)..BO

f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
64a633007e3d5a9a5943e417442548d6   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/grubx64.efi
64a633007e3d5a9a5943e417442548d6   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme1n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ng, update-grub,    farbios
nvme1n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme1n1p1   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme1n1p1   : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme1n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: E9057B1A-725B-4061-B4D9-69CB42819249
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048    2000895    1998848   976M EFI System
nvme0n1p2   2000896  226000895  224000000 106.8G Linux swap
nvme0n1p3 226000896 2000408575 1774407680 846.1G Linux filesystem
Disk nvme1n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0330F79D-FD16-4E3C-8924-F7EFFB3F6889
          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme1n1p1  2048 2000408575 2000406528 953.9G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 14.4 GiB, 15472047104 bytes, 30218842 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x02abf727
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 30218841 30216794 14.4G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:1049kB:15.5GB:15.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB:;
1:1049kB:1024MB:1023MB:fat32:Ubuntu_disk_1_EFI:boot, esp;
2:1024MB:116GB:115GB:linux-swap(v1):Ubuntu_disk_1_Swap:;
3:116GB:1024GB:908GB:ext4:Ubuntu_disk_1_data:;
nvme1n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB:;
1:1049kB:1024GB:1024GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      vfat     8C9B-AD3B                            02abf727-01                          UBUNTU 18_0 
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     FF1C-735F                            6978b9e0-60b5-402c-b99e-66b8b52c1a4e UBUNTU_SYS  Ubuntu_disk_1_EFI
├─nvme0n1p2 swap     23b8f6fb-b25a-4eeb-bf89-6ae259fdc657 f79ac9b7-ef8f-4ee4-be54-9d303865314e             Ubuntu_disk_1_Swap
└─nvme0n1p3 ext4     362f7a44-a9af-41ee-aa4c-be166f72152a 2ab522e5-2f43-44c2-9985-60224bc2d030 UBUNTU_1    Ubuntu_disk_1_data
nvme1n1                                                                                                    
└─nvme1n1p1 ext4     52d9c37d-7fea-4f4f-ae3f-a72310f1b6a1 8b83fa35-b1c9-4959-ae8e-c6e745bee868 DATA        

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

           Avail Use% Mounted on
nvme0n1p1 965.7M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
nvme0n1p3  35.5G  91% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
nvme1n1p1 890.1G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p1
sda1       12.5G  14% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1 rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
nvme0n1p3 rw,relatime
nvme1n1p1 rw,relatime
sda1      ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 362f7a44-a9af-41ee-aa4c-be166f72152a root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   362f7a44-a9af-41ee-aa4c-be166f72152a
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-45-generic   362f7a44-a9af-41ee-aa4c-be166f72152a
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-26-generic   362f7a44-a9af-41ee-aa4c-be166f72152a
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-37-generic   362f7a44-a9af-41ee-aa4c-be166f72152a
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
System setup   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p3/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme2n1p3 during installation
UUID=362f7a44-a9af-41ee-aa4c-be166f72152a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme1n1p2 during installation
# swap was on /dev/nvme2n1p2 during installation
UUID=23b8f6fb-b25a-4eeb-bf89-6ae259fdc657 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=cb8ed8a4-aedc-4627-bc4d-a670873a2129 / ext4 defaults,x-gvfs-show,noauto 0 2
UUID=FF1C-735F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme0n1p3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p3: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 943.896606445 = 1013.501263872 boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 746.625366211 = 801.682882560  boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-37-generic                  1
 702.500705719 = 754.304389120  boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic                  1
 672.086643219 = 721.647538176  boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-45-generic                  2
 673.530200958 = 723.197546496  boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-37-generic               6
 673.718219757 = 723.399430144  boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-26-generic               4
 674.085468292 = 723.793760256  boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-45-generic               7

=================== nvme0n1p3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12693 Mar 11 20:57 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 Mar 11 20:57 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Mar 11 20:57 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Mar 11 20:57 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Mar 11 20:57 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Mar 11 20:57 41_custom

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects

========================= sda1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[112831]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 7952: /bin/bash

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to sign-grub) and reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
nvme0n1p3,
using the following options:        nvme0n1p1/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-backups  

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________


Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```

Comment: That error means your bootloader is working properly. The error is occurring later in the boot cycle, after the bootloader has finished everything that it knows how to do. That kind of error occurs when init (pid 1) is trying to mount filesystems and encounters a problem. The error message should be longer than what you provided.

Comment: It looks like you fstab's UUID for / (root) is not the ext4 partition? And standard mount parameters for SSD as root `noatime,errors=remount-ro` I add noatime since SSD.

Comment: @user535733 it is the entire message: Did you remember to scroll through the entire message? But OK - I'm happy to hear that the re-creation of the boot-loader worked out well and that it is now "only" something about mounting it correct...I forgot to mentioned that I'm not a super user of Ubuntu - so please elaborate in depth when you are trying to help me out :-) What exactly should I try to do/change now? Which exact more info can I provide to you guys (I will update the post with images of my disk setup and partitions asap)?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm not a superuser of Ubuntu I'm not 100% what actually solved my issue - But I did the following:

1. Changed the EFI partition from: `/mnt/FF1C-735F` to `/boot`
2. Changed the partition with Ubuntu 18.04 from `mnt/some guid` to `/`
3. When I rebooted it stopped and reported this error: `stuck in emergency mode - FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found` --> I searched and found this solution: [16.04 - stuck in emergency mode - FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953681/16-04-stuck-in-emergency-mode-fat-fs-nvme0n1p1-io-charset-iso8859-1-not-f) --> I executed `depmod`, then I entered 'exit' and hit ENTER --> Ubuntu now starts up like before! Also after a reboot! :-)